# relative clause serving as subject or object

Tags: relative-clauses

I learned that in relative clauses , which or that can serve as a subject or object in the clause ,
 but I found the following sentence confusing.

> I learned so much more from books than I ever got out of the things **that they taught me at school.**

Why is the sentence above considered correct?
The relative clause itself is complete already, with ***they*** being the subject and ***me*** being the object of the relative clause,  what can the relativizer **that** serve as here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I learned so much more from books than I ever got out of the things*
>    *that they taught me at school*.

"That" is not actually a relative word, but a subordinator -- it plays no other role in the relative clause.

The relativised element in your example is missing and realised by the '____' notation, called 'gap', which has **things** as antecedent. It's diagrammed like this:

> *I learned so much more from books than I ever got out of the things* [ *that they taught me ____ at school* ].

It now becomes clear that "me" is indirect object and 'gap' is direct object.

Comment: Thanks, does "plays no other role" mean "plays the same rule"?

Answer (score 0):

**That** is also a *subordinate conjunction* that can be used to start *noun clauses* and *relative clauses.*

**Noun clause**:

> That he likes me is not important

Where *That he likes me* is the noun clause, performing the function of subject.

**Relative clause**:

> The things that they taught me are useless

Where *That they taught me* is the relative clause describing "the things", maybe what confused you here was the fact that *To teach* is a *ditransitive verb*, which is a verb that carries two objects:

> I taught him a lot of things

Where *him* is the second object *(a.k.a indirect object)* and *a lot of things* is the first object *(a.k.a direct object)*

In the example you used (The things that they taught me at school) *That* is serving as the direct object of the verb *Taught* if we turn it into a phrase, we get:

> They taught me the things at school

or

> They taught the things to me at school.

You could also replace *that* for *which*

> The things which they taught me at school.